# Dropdown Selection Only takes Last Selected Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am getting values from database into a drop down and I have to select one of the options from those.But when i am trying to select any option, the last value of that drop down list is getting selected automatically. i am using Angular js to bind the UI with database.

before selection : I was trying to select the second path from the drop down but the third path is getting selected automatically.

### Before

[image: Before selection]

### After

[image: After selection]

Comment: show your controller code if any related select box model.

Comment: provide your code on plunker

Comment: Most probably because of you are selecting the option in a loop, but, we can't do anything without your code.

Comment: $http({
        url: $rootScope.WebApiURL + '/getfolderattribute',
    }).
    success(function (data, status) {

        angular.forEach(data, function (value, key) {
            $scope.folderpaths = data;
        });
    });             : my js code

Comment: [HttpGet]
        [Route("getfolderattribute")]
        public object getfolderattribute()
        {
            LogUtilities.Info("Entered: getfolderpath webapi");

            try
            {
                return this.configurationServices.GetAllFolderAttributes();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogUtilities.Error(ex);
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }
        }                             : controller code!